# How to use object retrieved from method

Tags: c#, object, methods, polygon

I made a method to create a polygon with hexagonal shape and retrieve it as an object but I don't know how to use said object. The code is as follows:

```
    public object Hexagon()
    {
        float h;
        float r;
        int x = 20;
        int y = 20;
        int s = 10;

        h = HexOperations.ConvertToFloat(HexOperations.Calc(s));
        r = HexOperations.ConvertToFloat(HexOperations.Calc(s));

        Point[] vert= new Point[6];

        vert[0] = new Point(x, y);
        vert[1] = new Point(x + s, y);
        vert[2] = new Point(x + s + h, y + r);
        vert[3] = new Point(x + s, y + r + r);
        vert[4] = new Point(x, y + r + r);
        vert[5] = new Point(x - h, y + r);

        Polygon pol = new Polygon();

        System.Windows.Media.PointCollection pointC = new System.Windows.Media.PointCollection();

        pointC.Add(vert[0]);
        pointC.Add(vert[1]);
        pointC.Add(vert[2]);
        pointC.Add(vert[3]);
        pointC.Add(vert[4]);
        pointC.Add(vert[5]);

        pol.Points = pointC;

        pol.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

        return pol;
    }
```

If I add ´MainGrid.Children.Add(pol)´ before the return I can see the hexagon printed on the Grid ´MainGrid´ but I just don't know how to use it outside the said method. I've tried this:

```
    MainGrid.Children.Add(Hexagon());
```

Which gives me the error "cannot convert from ´object´ to System.Window.UIElement".

Also tried:

```
    Polygon poly = new Hexagon();
```

Which say "a new expression requires (). [], {}, ;, after type".

And:

```
    Hexagon poly = new Hexagon();
```

And this obviously gave me the finger. I just don't know what else to try. Probably because I'm making an elemental mistake with my approach but, anyways, thank you in advance.

Comment: `Hexagon()` is a function, not an object.  It is inappropriate to use `new` with it.   `Polygon poly = Hexagon();` should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is declared to return `object` - but you *know* it's a `Polygon`, so assuming you want callers to rely on it returning a `Polygon` (which seems reasonable) you should change the return type.

```
public Polygon Hexagon()
```

You also need to *call* the method, instead of either trying to use it as a type name with `new`, or passing it directly:

```
Polygon polygon = Hexagon();
// Use polygon here
```

I would also recommend:

- Naming the method with a verb, e.g. `CreateHexagon`
- Learning the basics of C# in console apps rather than GUIs - it's a lot simpler that way, which lets you focus on the one thing you're trying to learn, without being confused by the *huge* complexity of UI work

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you convert that `Object` to the required type using explicit conversion?

```
Polygon objPolygon =(Polygon)Hexagon();
```

I think this will solve your Problem. you can refer to more about conversions and casting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).